# Domain expired and can't register again!

Tags: domain-name, domain-registration

Hi my domain name expired, but I can't purchase it again as godaddy shows it's already taken and a whois returns the following:

```
Domain ID: 
Domain Name: mydomain.com
Created On: 26-Nov-2006 00:00:00
Expiration Date: 26-Nov-2009 00:00:00
Sponsoring Registrar: 'Check Whois' (WILDWESTDOMAINS) (WILDWESTDOMAINS)
Status: null
Name Server: ns13.domaincontrol.com
Name Server: ns14.domaincontrol.com
Registrant ID: Unknown
Registrant Name: Unknown
Registrant Organization: Unknown
Registrant Street1: Unknown
Registrant Street2: Unknown
Registrant Street3: Unknown
Registrant City: Unknown
Registrant State/Province: Unknown
Registrant Postal Code: Unknown
Registrant Country: Unknown
Registrant Phone: Unknown
Registrant Fax: Unknown
Registrant Email: Unknown
Admin ID: Unknown
Admin Name: Unknown 
Admin Organization: Unknown
Admin Street1: Unknown
Admin Street2: Unknown
Admin Street3: Unknown
Admin City: Unknown
Admin State: Unknown
Admin Postal Code: Unknown
Admin Country: Unknown
Admin Phone: Unknown
Admin Fax: Unknown
Admin Email: Unknown
```

Comment: The actual domain name at issue would be handy, so we can determine what's actually going on.

Answer (score 3):

It would appear that someone else has registered your domain, you only really have a few options:

- Talk to the new owner and see if the will sell it back to you
- [Register a dispute with ICAAN](http://www.icann.org/en/udrp/udrp.htm) to see if they they will give you it back (will be long winded and expensive)
- Move on and use a new domain.

Answer (score 1):

I believe GoDaddy puts expired names into a 'holding tank', a simple call to them would probably clear it up. BTW, wildwestdomains is a reseller for GoDaddy.

Answer (score -1):

The whole point of domain name expiration is that your domain expires and others get a shot at registering it. If you don't want to lose a domain name, don't let it expire.

Comment: -1 unhelpful comment, sometimes things happen that we don't plan for. If someone gets hit by a car, the last thing that matters at that point is their domain name.

Comment: So switch on automated renewal, or have a backup contact for an important domain. Registrars tend to start spamming you 90 days out when a domain payment is coming due, too. The system worked exactly as it should in this situation.

Comment: I am trying to get across that sometimes these things happens, it doesn't mean the OP is negligent; circumstances may have just conspired against him.

Comment: Doesn't matter what the circumstances are, the facts remain the same - once a domain has expired and been taken by someone else, you're in a world of hurt with no pleasant options.